# Accept or Reject Optimization

Tags: optimization, game-theory

Let's say that a player has some general idea of a distribution that random numbers will be drawn from.  The player will be presented a number and he can either accept or decline it. He will be offered a maximum of 10 numbers and needs to accept exactly 5.  The goal is to maximize the total of the 5 numbers.  I'll need to solve this (or simulate?) in a general case for N numbers presented and having to take T numbers.

Feels like game theory to me a bit, but it's been too long since I've done any real math so I could be totally off base.  I'd love to hear thoughts on how to reason and try to solve this problem in the general case.  I'm not sure where to even start.  Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have more structure on the way these numbers are drawn? Do you draw each number independently? With/without replacement?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but if $T=1$ then this is similar to the [secretary problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem) (which goes by many other names), which is itself a special case of an optimal stopping problem (though your problem is not an optimal stopping problem).

Comment: Numbers drawn without replacement and are independent.

Comment: The player knows that there are some terrible payouts, lots of minimal payouts, some slightly better, and a few great ones.  Logically when I do this in my head, I know to never take the terrible ones, but am not sure whether to take or pass on the minimal ones not knowing if the better ones will come or not.